# Why overload copy assignment operator for a singleton class in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I know why to make default constructor and copy constructor private to implement singleton class in C++. But what I don't understand is that why make copy assignment operator private, because there will not be two existing objects to start with.

My exploration brings two points:

1. According to Alexandrescu in "Modern C++ Design", the assignment
   operator to be made private to prevent self-assignment.
2. Second, according to [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), if you define one of ctor,
   copy ctor and assignment operator for a class, you should define
   explicitly all three. So, is it a matter of following this rule
   only.

So, what's your take on this?

Comment: I am not questioning Alexandrescu's explanation here! I want to know whether there is a technical reason or just to inform the client programmer that assignment is prevented? Because if we don't declare op= then programmers constructs like p1 = p2 would silently pass.

Comment: If you use a Singleton, then your design is already so bad, it's laughable that you'd then try to follow the Rule of Three.

Comment: Do you really want to allow this to compile? `S::getInstance() = S::getInstance();`

Answer (score 4):

I think, the need to prohibit the assignment is more in semantic considerations: as singleton is *unique*, the assignment for it doesn't have any sense. So if it would be even technically possible to implement assignment in a reasonable way, logically you need to prohibit it anyway.

So exactly because there must be never a need to copy a singleton, the operation has to be prohibited. Otherwise there is a room for confusion and mistakes: the developers *will* try to use it if it's allowed (and wonder what's wrong).

The good design minimizes the amount of WTFs.

Comment: But, let's decide to not provide it, even if client programmer is doing something like p1 = p2, (both are received from call to GetInstance()) self assignment would silently run and there is no harm since they are both referring to the same instance.

Comment: @Rajendra: well, they will wonder why their code doesn't work -- which is bad. Though technically it's perhaps possible. The good design is not only about technical correctness, it's about helping people to see what's going on.

Comment: So, they are made aware before they could even compile and run and wonder?

Comment: @Rajendra: Exactly. If something can be done at compile-time, it's (almost always) better to it at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

No.

In a Singleton you want to manage all possible construction, assignment and destruction. By making all those operations `private` you actually just prevent others from using them.

Also note that typically copy construction and copy assignment will be declared `private` to prevent invocation from outside but will not be defined because they are not used in practice... and so if they were the linker would complain.

In C++11 you would declare copy construction and copy assignment as `delete`d.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, one cannot use copy assignment if the constructors are private, as no one will be able to construct a valid lhs (except for self-assignment case).

Comment: @Matthieu: Is it necessary to declare op= or is it a style issue here?

Comment: @RajendraUppal: it is not just a style issue. Nonsensical operations should just be prohibited so that the message is clear: the user is warned that he did something nonsensical, and can react appropriately.